# Removing an unknown part of a string PHP

Tags: php, .htpasswd

I'm writing a PHP script that updates a .htpasswd file (yes, I know it's not very secure, but I have several protections to prevent people from accessing the script).

Right now, I'm just appending the current file, like that:

```
    $user = ''; // (Not an empty strings just removed the part that grabs this for security reasons)
    $password = ''; // (Not an empty strings just removed the part that grabs this for security reasons)
    $password = crypt($password, base64_encode($password));
    $line = $user . ':' . $password;
    $fh = fopen('path/to/password/file','a');
    fwrite($fh,$line);
    fclose($fh);
```

However, I'd like to remove any current entry on that person. If I knew what their old password was, for example `pass123`, I'd just use `str_replace($user . ':' . 'pass123','',$currentfiledata)`, but I don't, and I have no way to store it.

How would I be able to do this? I assume using `preg_replace` or something similar, but I'm not experienced with that.

Comment: Sidenote: Not only that, but a lot more work using a text file. Any special reason you're not using a database for this? (a lot more manageable too) *Just curious*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm developing something that'll be transferred from a domain to another regularly, and I can't use a database for that. I encrypt things into text files with keys I change daily. I know it's not very secure, but it's the best I can do.

Comment: Have you considered using SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a sane way to perform password updates. But since you already know that, I'm not going to lecture you about the security issues.

If you *must* do it this way, you can perform the replace using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) as below:

```
$currentfiledata = preg_replace('~^'.$user.':.*~m', '', $currentfiledata);
```

The above statement searches for any line that begins with (asserted by the anchor `^`) the given username, followed by a colon, and then the password (indicated by `.*` here - meaning any character, repeated zero or more times). The matches are replaced with an empty string.

Comment: Why the `m` modifier?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Umm, to make the anchors work multiline? Or do you not need it?